# Karma: Cannot read property of undefined in interceptor

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I'm getting an error in karma where my test fails:

```
Uncaught Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasPortalTokenInLocalStorage' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasPortalTokenInLocalStorage' of undefined
    at AuthenticationInterceptor.intercept (authentication.interceptor.ts:22
```

The strange thing is that it happens at a completely different test, where I should not even using that method.

The line of code in the interceptor where it fails is the following:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService) { }

public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    // The error happens here.
    if (this.authService.hasPortalTokenInLocalStorage()) {

            const ticketId: string = this.authService.getPortalTokenFromLocalStorage() as string;

            let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            headers = headers.append('Authorization', ticketId);

            request = request.clone({ headers });
        }

        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

So for some reason it cannot inject AuthenticationService.

Does anyone have an idea?

@Update
I provide the interceptor in my authentication.module (which is imported in the core.module, which is imported in the app.module) like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthenticationInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class AuthenticationModule { }
```

My AuthenticationService looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {

  private readonly localStorageParamName: string = 'portal.token';
  private readonly urlParamName: string = 'ticketId';

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  public getPortalTokenFromLocalStorage(): string | null {
    return localStorage.getItem(this.localStorageParamName);
  }

  public hasPortalTokenInLocalStorage(): boolean {
    return localStorage.getItem(this.localStorageParamName) != null;
  }

  // More methods here...

}
```

Comment: can you show the app.module, the import statement for the injector and the AuthenticationService

Comment: Sure, I just updated my post. Please tell me if you need more information.

Comment: Authservice has `getPortalTokenFromLocalStorage` but i cannot see `hasPortalTokenInLocalStorage` function

Comment: That's my bad, I deleted some more methods in order to keep it readable. Added `hasPortalTokenInLocalStorage()`.
But that wouldn't be the error. For some reason it can't initialize AuthService